# how to create button that always visible in foreground of any activity or homescreen?

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, homescreen

I want to make a button that float on homescreen and also work if any other activity is in running.
i have tricked many ideas and also google vary much but i can't get still any solution..

for example i have tried to make my application transparent and full screen and as a system alert flag from this stackoverflow question:   [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)

```
@Override

protected void onStop(){

    super.onStop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassNameOfYourActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and also tried to start my activity at every movement but it is very bad idea like this:
can't get any idea of doing this...Hopefully requested to share me any idea or example if you have experienced about this...
thanzzzz in advance..

Comment: In iOS we just add a view to the window, so that it is visible on every  view controller. I think there should be same kind of work around for Android. I am also searching for this for a while now.

Comment: I would use one `MainActivity` which will hold the button and add / remove Fragments for other "windows" of your application.

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani thnx... i don't know about ios but your suggestion may be useful to get new ideas...

Comment: @Android-Developer fragment is also good idea..thnx for that but i would like to know is can this fragment class use for **whole system???** I mean can we see and use this fragment either on homescreen or any of another application are running???
See this is demo application what i need (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shere.easytouch)